# How to render same form on the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm curious to know how this is done. Lets say I have a simple `Product` model and on one page wanted to click a link and add a product form by AJAX. I than pop up other product forms, finish the first one and submit it and do the same to the others.

Here is the code I will use.

---

On the index page you can add a product form by the link, create it and see it in a list.

**products/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Products</h1>

<%= link_to "Product", new_product_path, :remote => true %>

<div id="product_form">
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>

<ul id="products">
  <%= render :partial => @products.reverse %>
</ul>
```

**products/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@product, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**products/_product.html.erb**

```
<%= content_tag_for(:li, product) do %>
  <p><%= product.name</p>
  <p><%= product.price %></p>
<% end %>
```

**ProductsController**

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @product = Product.new
end

def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: "index" }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

When it gets created it should show the product in the `_product` partial.

**products/create.js.erb**

```
$('#products').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render(@product)) %>');
```

The link when clicked will make the product form appear in the `<div id="product_form">`

**products/new.js.erb**

```
$("#product-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'products/form', locals: { product: @product })) %>");
```

Now this generates one product form but I want to know the code logic behind rendering other product forms on the same page. How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do this with a second object representing the collection of products. This can be an activerecord if it fits your business logic (something like a ProductCategory, or a ShoppingCart) or a simple ActiveModel  "Products" with a save method that would save each of its related products.

[Active Presenter](https://github.com/jamesgolick/active_presenter) can give you more details of this mechanism but I wouldn't use that gem since it's activity is quite low.